# Apply styles to child of external component with styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have the following template in my Component.tsx

```
import {Foo} from 'external-stuff'
<Foo>
   <p>bar</p>
</Foo>
```

`Foo` is done so that it can accept a className

```
const Foo = ({className, title}) => {
   const Container = styled.div`
      // some styles
    `
   const Title = styled.div`
      border: 0;
    `
   const Content = styled.div`
      margin: 10px;
    `
   return ( 
      <Container className={className}>
           <Title>{title}</Title> 
           <Content>{children}</Content>
      </Container>
   )
```

What I need is to be able to add some styles to the `Title` and `Content` from Component.tsx since I don't have access to Foo.tsx. For example, I want to set border to `1px solid` instead of the default `0`

Comment: How about using class and tag name together? have tried that? Eg. .containerClass Title { // style here }

Comment: @VijayKumawat I need to do it with styled components not with plain css

Answer (score 0):

How about calling Styled versions of your `Foo` StyledComponents?:

```
import {Foo} from 'external-stuff'
import { Title, Content } from '//'

const StyledTitle = styled(Title)`
  border 1px solid;
`;

 return ( 
      <Container className={className}>
           <StyledTitle>{title}</StyledTitle> 
           <Content>{children}</Content>
      </Container>
   )
```

and so on..

I know this is how I've worked around similar issues on my projects!

Comment: Thanks fo the answer, but Title and Content are not exported..